# TinyMCE Printing HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

TinyMCE...

when I save form data, the text that was entered through the editor is being displayed with all of the tags in my index and detail view. Any idea how I can display the data as normal without html mark up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you outputting the text ?

I'd guess you should be using this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MceText)
```

Comment: Ah...and I was not using that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Do you also use it :  @Html.raw(modelItem => item.Message) as a substitute for Displayfor in a list?

Comment: You can but whether or not you should is a different matter! Because the HTMl is user generated, it may not be trustworthy. However, Html.Raw will simply emit the value requested without Html encoding it.

Comment: be careful about XSS attacks if you are gonna view the html code inside your page.